# Elasticsearch with different java heaps, does it matter?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, out-of-memory

Say, I've got 2 servers. One of which has `-xmx` and `-xms` set to `4G` and one to `2G`.
Will ElasticSearch handle those performance differences in the balancing mode? Or will both the servers be called purely based on indices, resulting in a (much more) likely `OOM` for the latter than the former?

By the way, I've set the properties `indices.fielddata.cache.size`, `indices.breaker.fielddata.limit`, `indices.breaker.request.limit`, and `indices.breaker.total.limit` on both servers as [ElasticSearch is suggesting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html#fielddata-size)

This is important, to me, because if it does, I'd have to change the index sharding on guessed index strain, which will be a hassle (if not impossible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch treats every nodes as the same and equally balances the documents between them. This means that Elasticsearch wont readjust based on hardware and get you the optimal performance.
One thing to remember here is that a herd of bulls is only as fast as its slowest bull. The same gets applied here. But then if the load is small enough that it does not eat up all the hardware for 2 GB machine ,then we should not be seeing any issue. Otherwise you should see difference in memory aggressive operations like aggregations.

Comment: Not necessarily the answer I was hoping for, though I understand why. According to your account, you are not guessing ;-). I have not began using aggregations, but when I do, I'll keep track of it (I hope I'll be able to supersize my servers by then, but don't assign more than 32 gigs of RAM per ES node, apparently)